# axapta2009: sum inventtrans on specific date, filter by dimension

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I need to calculate sum of InvnetTrans'es that have specific physicial dimensions[inventTransPosting.Dimension] on specific date. I.e. I need analogue of

```
select sum(CostAmountPosted) //other sums
     from InventTrans 
     where  InventTrans.transDate  < 3\3\2010
exists join InventTransPosted 
    where InventTransPosted.dimension[1] == 'XXX'
       && InventTransPosted.inventTransId == inventTrans.inventTransId
       && //other relations
```

It is possible to calculate InvenTrans sum with InventSum* classes filtering InvenTranses by InventDim.
Is it possible somehow to filter by non inventdim dimensions?
Or it is neccessary to change InventSum* classes? 
Right now I don't see that inventSum* classes can filter by Dimensions. Maybe I missed some classes?

Comment: "Physical dimensions" is not stored in the `Dimension` field. The `Dimension` stores financial dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restructure your select:

```
select sum(CostAmountPosted) //other sums
     from InventTrans 
exists join InventTransPosting
    where InventTransPosting.dimension[1] == 'XXX'
       && InventTransPosting.transDate  < 3\3\2010
       && InventTransPosting.inventTransId == inventTrans.inventTransId
       && InventTransPosting.itemId == inventTrans.itemId
       && //other relations
```

Make relevant index on InventTransPosting with `Dimension[1]` as first index field and `TransDate` as second.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the `InventOnHand` class.

It sums the invent on-hand values based on criteria like item id and inventory dimensions (but not financial dimensions).

There are several constructor methods to `InventOnhand` name new like `newInventBatch`.

Comment: Well, it doesn't look helpful unfortunately then. Looks like I have no choice but to sum all inventrans: inventSum has no links to dimensions[] at all, so subtracting inventTrans from inventSum can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could store - redundantly - `amountPosted` on `InventTransPosted` table, then make a relevant index.

The filling of the `amountPosted` on existing transaction may be problematic.

Is it worth it?
Or could you use a BI tool to do your report?